# trouble building libcanberra-0.25 on CentOS 5

Tags: linux, compilation, configure, centos5

I'm trying to build Chromium for CentOS 5. This is problematic because the libraries are old in this distro and so some need to be build manually for it.
I'm following the post linked below which explains what needs to be built locally, in order to build Chromium for CentOS.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=26809&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=26809 (comment 17)

I managed to build all the other libraries in the list, but I'm stuck on libcanberra.
The list requires that I build libtool-2.2.8. I have done so sucessfully.
It then requires that I build libcanberra-0.25
However, when I run ./configure for canberra, I get:

```
checking ltdl.h usability... yes
checking ltdl.h presence... yes
checking for ltdl.h... yes
checking for lt_dladvise_init in -lltdl... no
configure: error: Unable to find libltdl.
```

I don't understand what it's looking for and where. lt_dladvise_init is indeed not present in the ltdl.h file, though I've read that it should be available from version 2.2 of libtools.
Any help with this issue would be hugely appreciated.

The full ./configure log:

```
    [user@localhost libcanberra-0.25]$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 needs -traditional... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wall flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -W flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wextra flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -pedantic flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -pipe flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wno-long-long flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Winline flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wvla flag... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wno-overlength-strings flag... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wundef flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wformat=2 flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wlogical-op flag... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wsign-compare flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wpacked flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wformat-security flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wmissing-include-dirs flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wformat-nonliteral flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wold-style-definition flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wpointer-arith flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Winit-self flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wdeclaration-after-statement flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wfloat-equal flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wmissing-declarations flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wmissing-prototypes flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wstrict-prototypes flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wredundant-decls flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wmissing-noreturn flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wshadow flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wendif-labels flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wstrict-aliasing=2 flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wcast-align flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wwrite-strings flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wno-unused-parameter flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -ffast-math flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-common flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fdiagnostics-show-option flag... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-strict-aliasing flag... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 98304
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... no
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking ltdl.h usability... yes
checking ltdl.h presence... yes
checking for ltdl.h... yes
checking for lt_dladvise_init in -lltdl... no
configure: error: Unable to find libltdl.
```

Comment: It looks like you've got the devel package installed but not the actual lib, try installing it with `yum install libtool-ltdl` found by doing a `yum search ltdl` on my system

Comment: Actually, I got the libtool-2.2.8 library and built it myself using *./configure* and *sudo make install*. Looked like it built fine. I looked at ltdl.c and ltdl.h and lt_dladvise_init IS defined there. It must have something to do with the way ./configure tests for the functionality it's looking for.

Comment: Just on the off-chance that building it myself did not get it done right, I reinstalled the libtool-ltdl-1.5.22-7 and it did not help in any way...